# Evaluate power and efficiency in opamp, exercise

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework

Can you help me with this exercise?

> An amplifier operating from a single 15-V supply provides a 12-V peak-to-peak sine-wave signal to a 1- kΩ load and draws negligible input current from the signal source. The dc current drawn from the 15-V supply is 8 mA. What is the power dissipated in the amplifier, and what is the amplifier efficiency?

My solution (wrong);

Pload = (12V / Rload) * 12V
Psupply = 15V * 8mA

Pdiss = Psupply - Pload

New solution;

Vorms = 12V / (2*sqrt(2)) = 4.24V

Pload = (Vorms / Rload) * Vorms = 0.618 mW
Psupply = 15V * 8mA = 120 mW

Pdiss = Psupply - Pload = 119.4 mW

Efficiency = (Pload / Psupply) * 100 = 0.515

I think it is still wrong, the results seem too bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: @Hearth is right.I've posted many of my queries too, but I always made it a point to mention how far I have tried to solve my problem, or mentioned what I was thinking so that the effort shows. If you show your work,then people here will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @SM32 ok I will post my solution in a sec, but I know that is wrong

Comment: The clue in the question is "peak to peak". You need the RMS voltage to compute the power in the load.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks you, I have read better now. Then I have to calculate for example 12V/sqrt(2) for the output rms value, correct?

Comment: @Andrea closer but not correct.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Why not? Is not that the rms value for Vout?

Comment: No it isn't. Do some reading on the difference between peak, peak to peak, and RMS.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ok, done. Because it is peak to peak and not only the peak, I have to divide for 2. The Vorms=vo/(2sqrt(2))

Comment: So update your question.  Do you have the correct answer now?

Comment: @KH Okay, I'll update the question in a second. I'm not sure if that's right, I would like confirmation.

Comment: Can anyone check my results. I think I still miss understanding something.

Comment: It may be helpful to put that circuit into some simulator like LTspice and then you can measure the currents and device dissipation, and see whether the simulation agrees with your derivation, and if not then you can see exactly where the error is (hopefully).

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica thanks you for the advice, i'will try. I know that is a simple exercise, but I'm very bad in analog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The dc current drawn from the 15-V supply is 8 mA.*

Calculate total power into circuit like this: power = Vdc * Idc = 0.12 watts.

> *...provides a 12-V peak-to-peak sine-wave signal to a 1- kΩ load*

The RMS voltage is 4.243 volts (figure that out) hence the power in the load is 18 mW (again you should figure that out yourself).

The Power dissipated in the amplifier is the difference i.e. 0.102 W

The efficiency is power out / power in * 100% = 15%.

**Please don't repost questions in the future.**